# Aggregation search in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, aggregate-functions

I intend to search through bunch of logs in Kibana. I need results based on aggregation like grouping logs based on one field or other aggregation method. Like one with SQL, GROUP BY operation. I didn't come across any method whether you could do it in Kibana dashboard. Is there any method to do it in Kibana Query Language?

Kibana offers some kind aggregation method in visualization section. But I find it time-consuming every time I switch to visualization. What I want is functions in Query Language whereby I can use it frequently without losing time on configuring it on interface.

Comment: I think [ES|QL](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-language-esql) will help you once it's released in 8.11